# Passing document() parameter to an xslt in XProc pipeline

Tags: xslt, xproc

I've set up an XProc pipeline wherein I have a `<p:xslt>` step. Amoung the parameters of this stylesheet, I have an parameter which is a document() node:

This is the km_to_dita.xsl stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dctm="http://www.documentum.com" xmlns:ale="http://www.amplexor.com/alcatel"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs dctm ale" version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="conf-base" select="'file:/D:/Temp/ALE_config/'" />

    <xsl:param name="output-base" select="''"/>

    <xsl:param name="lang" select="/element()[1]/@language"/>

    <xsl:param name="graphics-reference-names" as="document-node()*" />

    <!-- my templates stuff... -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thus I am calling this XSLT in my pipeline with the following step (for demonstration purpose it is set with a `<p:inline>` but it is aimed to be bound to the result port of a step):

```
<p:xslt name="km-dm-to-dita">
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:pipe port="list-dm" step="list-csv"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:input port="stylesheet">
        <p:document href="km_to_dita.xsl"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:with-param name="output-base" select="$dita.data-dir"/>
    <p:with-param name="conf-base" select="$config-dir"/>
    <!--<p:with-param name="graphics-reference-names">
        <p:pipe port="result" step="get-figure-references"/>
    </p:with-param>-->
    <p:with-param name="graphics-reference-names">
        <p:inline>
            <graphic-ids>
                <reference type="symbol" document="dm09011b0281121ef3.xml#G4" filename="g09011b0281d9c449.gif"/>
                <reference type="symbol" document="dm09011b0281121ef3.xml#G3" filename="g09011b0281d9c449.gif"/>
                <reference type="figure" document="dm09011b0281121ef3.xml#F33" filename="g09011b0281d9c44d.gif"/>
                <reference type="symbol" document="dm09011b0281121ef3.xml#G5" filename="g09011b0281d9c451.gif"/>
                <reference type="figure" document="dm09011b0281121ef5.xml#F116" filename="g09011b0281d9c458.gif"/>
            </graphic-ids>
        </p:inline>
    </p:with-param>

    <p:with-option name="output-base-uri" select="$dita.data-dir"/>
</p:xslt>
```

But it fails when running it with XML Calabash (in oXygenXML), the error being raised is (sorry folks it's all the information I have) however have determined that it's the `<p:with-param name="graphics-reference-names">` that causes this error):

> null

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found what's going wrong with it... First of all, the `<p:with-param>` is missing the required `@select` attribute, as mentioned [in the XProc](https://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/#p.with-param), but strangely oXygen didn't raise any validating error for my pipeline.

Thus the pipeline may be fixed that way:

```
<p:with-param name="graphics-reference-names" select="/">
    <p:inline>
        <graphic-ids>
            <reference type="symbol" document="dm09011b0281121ef3.xml#G4" filename="g09011b0281d9c449.gif"/>
            <reference type="symbol" document="dm09011b0281121ef3.xml#G3" filename="g09011b0281d9c449.gif"/>
            <reference type="figure" document="dm09011b0281121ef3.xml#F33" filename="g09011b0281d9c44d.gif"/>
            <reference type="symbol" document="dm09011b0281121ef3.xml#G5" filename="g09011b0281d9c451.gif"/>
            <reference type="figure" document="dm09011b0281121ef5.xml#F116" filename="g09011b0281d9c458.gif"/>
        </graphic-ids>
    </p:inline>
</p:with-param>
```

With the solution above, XSLT fails because the parameter is casted to a string:

> Required item type of value of variable $graphics-reference-names is document-node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

This is the other issue that makes the problem unsolvable: XProc allows only parameters to be set as atomic values, as explained in [XSLT with XProc - parameter binding in the required type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861633/xslt-with-xproc-parameter-binding-in-the-required-type).

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
<p:input port="source">
    <p:pipe port="list-dm" step="list-csv"/>
    <p:pipe port="result" step="your-other-step"/>
</p:input>
```

in XProc 1 with `p:xslt version="2.0"` and then

```
<xsl:param name="graphics-reference-names" as="document-node()*" select="subsequence(collection(), 2)" />
```

in the XSLT code I think it should work to have the result of another step available as a secondary input document (accessed as part of the default collection).